# Changing the host of my CakePHP site

Tags: database, cakephp, host

I bought an application made in ​​Cakephp, everything was fine before, but once I wanted to host it on another server  (with keeping the same database and folders), I find the links to the CSS, JavaScript and images do not work.

Please I have no knowledge in CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clean up the database?
I had to change some entries by hand once, because the servername/ip/url didn't change.

go to your db management system and search for your old IP/Path/domainname etc....

Comment: I just checked it out, but I found nothing

Comment: start the network console/developer console and check the urls. maybe the directory is wrong or you disabled access to the data.

Comment: do you use firefox or chrome?Chrome: Control+Shift+I, klick network and press F5...check the urls for mistakes. Firefox: Control+Shift+K

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy over the (often hidden) .htaccess files when you moved to the new host?

There are three .htaccess files, one in the root of your site, on in the /app directory, and one in /app/webroot

Is mod_rewrite enabled on your new server?